# Multiple DB in meteor keeping reactivity

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

There's some way to use more than one MongoDB database in meteor keeping reactivity/Oplog working? I've been reading about it [(Post1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28787886/meteor-database-connection), [(Post2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535755/using-multiple-mongodb-databases-with-meteor-js) and still I don't see a straighforward way to achieve this. It's possible? What's the right way? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say; `Default Connection` isn't really an option as you can only have one DB and `DDP` is a bit superfluous when you only need a DB and none of the Meteor stuff. I'd think, therefore, your best approach would be to use the `MongoInternals` option.

The only thing missing from that option is reactivity; a method of enabling oplog tailing for these additional DB connections is mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34348478/5572188). It essentially seems to be a case of passing the oplogUrl when creating the `RemoteCollectionDriver`, here's the example given in their answer:

```
var driver = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver(
    "mongodb://localhost:27017/db", 
    {
      oplogUrl: "mongodb://localhost:27017/local"
    });
var collection = new Mongo.Collection("Coll", {_driver: driver});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to write here what I've discovered until now, but I'm not going to mark the question as answered.

## Concepts

#### What is reactivity?

Using reactivity, the data you show to your users will be updated in real time. You can enable or disable reactivity when you subscribe to a collection. Like this:

```
// enabled by default
Meteor.publish('top', function() {
  return Top.find({},{reactive: false});
});
```

#### What is oplog?

Oplog is the MongoDB log. When you tell meteor to use oplog, reactivity performance is much better, unless you have a really high volumne of insert operations. In this cases may be wise to keep it disabled. Oplog can optimize your reactive DB calls [by ~x5 ~x20](https://meteorhacks.com/making-meteor-500-faster-with-smart-collections/).If you are going to use oplog you should optimize your db calls. You can read more about it [here](https://kadira.io/academy/meteor-performance-101/content/optimize-your-app-for-oplog).

## What methods exists to connect DBS to meteor?

#### Default connection:

Reactivity? yes. Oplog? yes. DB Limit? One. Description: Meteor creates a default MongoDB database when you run 'meteor'. You can set a different database using enviromental variables, or just `MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/db_name meteor`.

#### DDP:

Reactivity? yes. Oplog? yes. DB Limit? no. Description: You need a meteor project for every DB. That's about 600MB in memory for every DB. You can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20537457/2010764) and [here](http://docs.meteor.com/api/connections.html#DDP-connect).

#### MongoInternal (**SOLUTION:** Thanks to carlevans719):

Reactivity? yes. Oplog? yes. DB Limit? no. Description: You can specify a DB in your subscriptions file like:

```
ar database = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver('mongodb://user:password@localhost:27017/meteor', {oplogUrl: "mongodb://localhost:27017/local"});
var numberOfDocs = database.open('boxes').find().count();
```

#### Last Words:

MongoInternal If you are not going to use the default db, you have to tell meteor to do not create it. To achieve this you must always run meteor as `MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017 meteor`